# mongodb $lookup in array inside array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi i want to get the product details from product collection and the product id is present in an array in order collection .
i have an order collection like this :

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("59267748c1f80b17cd53a7bd"),
"updatedAt": ISODate("2017-05-25T06:33:41.827Z"),
"createdAt": ISODate("2017-05-25T06:18:48.264Z"),
"createdBy": "58ba6b8356a7bf05f613cda0",
"status": "shipment",
"productDetails": [
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("59267997c1f80b17cd53a7da"),
        "productCatalogId": "592677eac1f80b17cd53a7be",
        "quantity": 2,
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": "5926791bc1f80b17cd53a7d1",
                "_id": ObjectId("59267a94c1f80b17cd53a7ee")
            },
            {
                "productId": "5926793bc1f80b17cd53a7d3",
                "_id": ObjectId("59267aacc1f80b17cd53a7ef")
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("592679a1c1f80b17cd53a7db"),
        "productCatalogId": "592678a5c1f80b17cd53a7c5",
        "quantity": 1,
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": "59267959c1f80b17cd53a7d5",
                "_id": ObjectId("59267ac5c1f80b17cd53a7f0")
            }
        ]
    }
],
"__v": 0,
"OrderedFor": "58ba6b8356a7bf05f613cda0",
"billingId": ObjectId("592679d2c1f80b17cd53a7e2"),
"shipmentId": ObjectId("592679d2c1f80b17cd53a7e3")
 }
```

and the products collection is :

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5926791bc1f80b17cd53a7d0"),
"updatedAt": ISODate("2017-05-25T06:32:52.590Z"),
"createdAt": ISODate("2017-05-25T06:26:35.529Z"),
"productCatalogId": "592677eac1f80b17cd53a7be",
"batch": "2017-05-25T06:26:35.510Z",
"createdBy": "58be7c914e5db93569289d27",
"products": [
    {
        "updatedAt": ISODate("2017-05-25T06:26:35.528Z"),
        "createdAt": ISODate("2017-05-25T06:26:35.528Z"),
        "serialno": "1016SAM0001",
        "mfgdate": ISODate("2017-04-21T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "mfgbatch": "1016",
        "updatedBy": "58be7c914e5db93569289d27",
        "_id": ObjectId("5926791bc1f80b17cd53a7d1"),
        "status": "sold",
        "addOnSerialnos": [
            "1016RAK0001",
            "1016SUJ0001"
        ]
    }
],
"__v": 0
}
```

My **query** is

```
Order.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: req.params.id } },
    { $unwind: "$productDetails.products" },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Product",
            localField: "productDetails.products",
            foreignField: "products._id",
            as: "products_docs"
        }
    }, {
        $match: { "products_docs": { $ne: [] } }
    }
], function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    return res.json(result);
});
```

my order model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var orderProductSchema = new Schema({
 productCatalogId: { type: Object, ref: "ProductCatalog" },
 products: [{ productId: { type: Object, ref: "Product.products" } }],
 quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 }
});

var orderSchema = new Schema({
OrderedFor: { type: Object, ref: 'User' },
billingId: { type: Object, ref: "Billing" },
shipmentId: { type: Object, ref: "Shipment" },
productDetails: [orderProductSchema],
status: { type: String, default: "init" },
createdBy: { type: Object, ref: 'User' },
updateBy: { type: Object, ref: 'User' },
 }, {
 timestamps: true
 });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

and my product model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productSchema = new Schema({
imeino: String,
serialno: String,
addOnSerialnos: [String],
mfgdate: Date,
mfgbatch: String,
status: { type: String, default: "in-stock" },
updatedBy: { type: Object, ref: "User" },
}, {
timestamps: true
});

var productDetailSchema = new Schema({
productCatalogId: { type: Object, ref: 'ProductCatalog' },
batch: String,
inventoryId: { type: Object, ref: "Inventory" },
createdBy: { type: Object, ref: "User" },
products: [productSchema],
}, {
timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productDetailSchema);
```

Which is not working (*getting empty array*) , can anyone please help me to solve this ?

Comment: You need to `$unwind` the `"productDetails"` array **before** you do the `$unwind` on the "inner" `"productDetails.products"`. Whilst it is possible for `$lookup` to reference a `"localField"` property which is an array, it does need to be a "flat" array with no nested documents. Modification of inner properties of an array is not supported. Does not error, but the result will always be an empty array, So just do the other `$unwind` first.

Comment: I tried but still it is giving empty array.

Comment: Can you amend your question to include some valid actual documents please. In that way we can see some data to perform a test.

Comment: You have a few problems here. For starters since you are using mongoose I then presume the actual collection name ( as opposed to the model name ) here is `"products" ( which is the Mongoose pluralize rule ), and since `$lookup` runs on the server it knows only the collection name. Aside from other syntax issues, the main thing is the values in the `"products"` array. Does either `ObjectId("59267a94c1f80b17cd53a7ee")` or `ObjectId("5926791bc1f80b17cd53a7d1")` actually appear in the `"products"` collection? Best to check in the shell

Comment: I'm also guessing you have schema definition problems. This does not directly affect this operation. But the effect here is noting that in the `"products"` array the `"_id"` field is an `ObjectId` and the `"productId"` is not. Presumably `"productId"` has been declared as a `String` rather then and `ObjectId` that should also have a `"ref"` to the `Product` model. So the values I asked you to check would represent a problem it it is the second one ( the productId value ) that is the match. Since on one collection it is a string and in the other an `ObjectId`.

Comment: You should include your current schema definitions in the question if you are going to need help in fixing this problem with the schema.

Comment: included models also @NeilLunn

Comment: Okay that let's me see the error in definition. The lines where you use type `Object` should have been `Schema.types.ObjectId`. Damage is done there, so the data requires fixing. What about the searches from the "products" collection I asked you to do? This `ObjectId("5926791bc1f80b17cd53a7d1")` should match the `_id` of a document in that collection. And that should also be the document from that collection you show in your question, so at least something would be matched by a `$lookup`. When the data is fixed of course.

Comment: You mean in order schema ?? i need to change as Schema.types.ObjectId?

Comment: I mean "everwhere" you typed `Object`. Have a look at your documents. Values like this `"productId": "5926791bc1f80b17cd53a7d1"` should be `"productId": ObjectId("5926791bc1f80b17cd53a7d1")` but are not because you used the wrong type. Mongoose then just took the values as "strings", and `$lookup` nor `.populate()` will work since `"5926791bc1f80b17cd53a7d1" == ObjectId("5926791bc1f80b17cd53a7d1")` is false. They are different types and will never match. It's also somewhat redundant to have things like both `_id` and `product_id` in the array where your intention was references.